# File Indexing tool for Solr

Tags: gratis, database

I'm looking for a free tool that indexes files to Solr and is suited for a production environment. It has to be able to ignore files that havent changed since the last index as well as finishing a very large amount of files in a reasonable timeframe.

I have already tried ManifoldCF, but am unable to use it due to a possible memory bug. The Simple Post Tool can be ruled out, as it isn't designed for production use.